# Extract Excel XML information in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xml

Well, once again I ask for your help, I have an XML that provides information of excel, what I intended was to remove all information (MAIL USER PASS) that are in this excerpt taken from the XML.

```html
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s62" ss:HRef="mailto:joao@bolotas.com">
<Data ss:Type="String">joao@gmail.com</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">: user: Joao || Pass : user3</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s62" ss:HRef="mailto:carlos@gmail.com">
<Data ss:Type="String">carlos@bolotas.com</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">: user: Carlos || Pass : user4</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s62" ss:HRef="mailto:paulo@clix.com">
<Data ss:Type="String">carlos@clix.com</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">: user: Paulo || Pass : user1</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s62" ss:HRef="mailto:ricardo@clix.com">
<Data ss:Type="String">ricardo@clix.com</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">: user: Ricardo || Pass : user52</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
<Cell ss:StyleID="s62" ss:HRef="mailto:santos@clix.com">
<Data ss:Type="String">santos@clix.com</Data>
</Cell>
<Cell>
<Data ss:Type="String">: user: santos || Pass : user9</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
```

I have a document in echo php but I can not retrieve the information that is in the box above and I have come to ask for your help in solving this problem.

Attached I leave the full XML link (http://trabalhos.6te.net/TesteXML.xml) and also echo php

```html
<?php
$data = array();
 
function add_person( $first, $middle, $last, $email )
{
global $data;
 
$data []= array(
'first' => $first,
'middle' => $middle,
'last' => $last,
'email' => $email 
);
}
 
if ( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] )
{
$dom = DOMDocument::load( $_FILES['http://trabalhos.6te.net/TesteXML.xml']['tmp_name'] );
$rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'Row' );
$first_row = true;
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
if ( !$first_row )
{
$first = "";
$middle = "";
$last = "";
$email = "";
 
$index = 1;
$cells = $row->getElementsByTagName( 'Cell' );
foreach( $cells as $cell )
{ 
$ind = $cell->getAttribute( 'Index' );
if ( $ind != null ) $index = $ind;
 
if ( $index == 1 ) $first = $cell->nodeValue;
if ( $index == 2 ) $middle = $cell->nodeValue;
if ( $index == 3 ) $last = $cell->nodeValue;
if ( $index == 4 ) $email = $cell->nodeValue;
 
$index += 1;
}
add_person( $first, $middle, $last, $email );
}
$first_row = false;
}
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>First</th>
<th>Middle</th>
<th>Last</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach( $data as $row ) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo( $row['first'] ); ?></td>
<td><?php echo( $row['middle'] ); ?></td>
<td><?php echo( $row['last'] ); ?></td>
<td><?php echo( $row['email'] ); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks first of all for the help in solving my problem.

Comment: I don't understand the goal. You need to extract the information from XML e put it in an HTML table? Or you want to remove information from XML?

Comment: @OscarZarrus I want to remove the xml information in an HTML table, but I can not.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm a little bit stupid, but I can't reach your goal. Please produce an output example.

Comment: @OscarZarrus I should not have explained it well, what I intend is to get a php code where I can get access to the information about the user; Pass that is in the excerpt that I put in the view that is inside the <Row> function. I tried to drag a code to provide this information may not be this. Sorry I can not explain it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Let's start a step by step

Before we parse XML into an array:

```
$xmlFile = file_get_contents("http://trabalhos.6te.net/TesteXML.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlFile);
$Rows = $xml->Worksheet->Table; // take the Worksheet tag from object and take Table inside it...
$i = 0;
$results = array();
 // loop through the user data
foreach ($Rows->Row as $r){
    if ($i === 0){$i++;continue;}
    $email = (array)$r->Cell[0]->Data;
    $email = $email[0];
    $user = (array)$r->Cell[1]->Data;
    $user = $user[0];

    $results[] = array(
            'email' => $email,
            'user' => $user
    );
    $i++;

}
```

it will produce this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => joao@gmail.com
            [user] => : user: Joao || Pass : user3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => carlos@bolotas.com
            [user] => : user: Carlos || Pass : user4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => carlos@clix.com
            [user] => : user: Paulo || Pass : user1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [email] => ricardo@clix.com
            [user] => : user: Ricardo || Pass : user52
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [email] => santos@clix.com
            [user] => : user: santos || Pass : user9
        )

)
```